# pandas resample avoid missing dates while upsampling

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Is it possible to skip/avoid the dates, with missing data or zeros, created during pandas resampling (upsampling)? I can filter them out later, but is some option already there, which will be much faster?

Comment: depends of data the best test with your real data

Comment: If it’s possible to instead `groupby` using datetime attributes, this will result in only groups that exist.